# Passing Shape Properties to _Click() Sub

Tags: excel, parameter-passing, vba

I am struggling to even figure out where to start here, so any push in the right direction will be of great help.

I have a map spreadsheet with many different rectangle objects that contain text. When I click on a Rectangle I want to run a macro and I want that macro to receive the text in the rectangle as a parameter. The goal is to get this to display a `userform` complete with a `listbox` table that would be custom created based off of the text in the rectangle. I know how to do the latter, but I'm blanking on how to get this property from a shape object. I figured it would be something like this?

```
Sub Rectangle205_Click()
    facilityName = Me.Text
End Sub
```

or

```
Sub AMacro(By Ref Target)
    facilityName = Target.Text
End Sub
```

I am pretty clueless on this one, so your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use first code below to link every shapes in a specific sheet to the `get_text` code:

```
Sub apply_script()

Dim sh As Shape

For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    sh.OnAction = "get_text"
Next

End Sub
```

Then use this code to get the text of the shape:

```
Sub get_text()
    MsgBox ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TextFrame.Characters.Caption
End Sub
```

Edit for rectangles only :

```
Sub apply_script()

Dim sh As Shape

For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If sh.AutoShapeType = 1 Then
        sh.OnAction = "get_text"
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Works perfectly as intended. Thank you! I will read more into the .OnAction method and Application.Caller.

Comment: Is there a way to screen the shapes and only add shapes of the rectangle variety to my `"get_text"` action. What property would I access?